# Excel formula needed for a 2-D array lookup in separate worksheets

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, 2d, vlookup

Is there a formula in Excel that will do a 2-D array lookup in separate worksheets inside a single workbook?

I have three tables formatted identically with different data in the tables. Each table is located in a separate worksheet.

Table 1: Carbon Steel Welding Man-hours (CS)
Table 2: Stainless Steel Welding Man-hours (SS)
Table 3: Aluminum Welding Man-hours (Al)

[image: Please see link below for table format]

Note: y-axis: pipe diameter, x-axis: pipe schedule(thickness)

I want the formula to identify the material type (CS,SS,Al) in the "summary sheet", and use the correct "man-hour table" inside the correct worksheet. The formula must then perform a 2-D array lookup (y-axis: pipe diameter, x-axis: pipe schedule "thickness"), and display the correct data from the "man-hour table" in the "summary sheet".

[image: PLease see link below for summary sheet format]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the Volatile `INDIRECT` function, use a nested IF to lookup each sheet.

```
=IF(A5="CS",INDEX(CS!Table,MATCH(...),MATCH(...)),IF(A5="AL",INDEX(AL!Table,MATCH(...),MATCH(...)),IF(A5="SS",INDEX(SS!Table,MATCH(...),MATCH(...)),"")))
```

Note: Excel formula If is short circuited, so only one INDEX/MATCH will be executed

Answer (score 0):

Use INDIRECT to return the correct sheet and INDEX/MATCH/MATCH to get the correct MH:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & A5 &"'!A:X"),MATCH(B5,INDIRECT("'" & A5 &"'!A:A"),0),MATCH(C5,INDIRECT("'" & A5 &"'!5:5"),0))
```